# Pick position of a particular list in the list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, code-request

Suppose I have some following lists with different size

```
 A1 = {a1, a2, a3, a4};
 A2 = {a2, a5, a8};
 A3 = {a5};
 A4 = {a1, a2, a3, a4};
 B1 = {b1, b2, b3};
 B2 = {b2};
 B3 = {b4, b5, b9, b12};
 C1 = {c1, c2};
```

Now I can make lists of lists as

```
 TL = {A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, C1};
```

I want to make a function whose input is lists of lists and the target list, so that if the target list is in lists of list print its position and the its input.

More explicitly if I design my function

```
 F[ListofList_, List]
```

on the above examples, i.e., $F[TL,A1]$ gives 1. or $F[{{a1,a2},{b1,b2,b3},{c1}}, {c1}] =3$

---

My first tiral is using the command Select; If I implement the following things

```
 Select[TL,#=={a1,a2,a3,a4}]
```

it pops out

```
 {{a1, a2, a3, a4}, {a1, a2, a3, a4}}
```

so it shows that there are at least two list $\{a1,a2,a3,a4\}$ in the given lists of list TL. But this does not gives where the target list $\{a1,a2,a3,a4\}$ located in the input list.

Comment: try `PositionIndex` (e.g. `PositionIndex[TL]@{a1, a2, a3, a4}`)

Comment: Also, the part of a function definition that you gave has bad syntax. Using @kglr solution, `F[ListofList_List, tgt_List] := PositionIndex[ListofList]@tgt`

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but what is wrong with `Position[TL, {a2,a2,a3,a4}]` here?  (And the output is in the correct format for `Extract`)